# Проверка кода активации

Tags: javascript, php

Мне нужно, чтобы при загрузке страницы выполнялась проверка кода в хэше и если код есть в базе, то отображался текст (например, при check.html#code=123). Как это можно сделать или как хотя бы гуглить, потому что авторизация с логином\паролем, как я понимаю, это немного другое.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во первых, хеш не передается на сервер - эта часть доступна только c клиента. Поэтому полюбому придется отправлять `ajax`-запрос.

```
const contentContainer = document.querySelector("#someElement");
const code = location.hash.split("code=")[1];
if(code){
  const endpoint = "/getMyData.php?code=" + code;
  const result = await fetch(endpoint).then(response => response.text());
  contentContainer.innerText = result;
}
```

---

**getMyData.php** может выглядить как-то так:

```
<?php
$code = $_GET["code"];
$code = preg_replace("/[^0-9A-Za-z_]/", "", $code);

$text = $gb->get("tableName", "text", [
  "code" => $code,
]);

echo $text;
```

В этом примере я делал запрос в базу не с помощью прямого запроса, а использовал библиотеку [Medoo](https://medoo.in/). Это легковесная библиотека, которая упрощает работу с БД на php.